# Play 2.5.x: How to change the default evolutions directory location?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, slick

Is there a way to change the default evolutions directory location? I need this because I have the following apparently rare use-case:

- For Dev/Prod I use a `default` database Postgres
- For Unit testing I need to use an H2 in-memory database
- `evolutions/default/1.sql` is portable (Postgres & H2)
- `evolutions/default/2.sql` is non portable Postgres script
- In Dev/Prod I need evolutions to run `1.sql` and `2.sql`
- In Unit tests I need evolutions to run only `1.sql`

Is there a way to using `application.conf` or some `sbt` setting alla e.g.

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf"
```

be able to change the default directory of evolutions for `test`?

My OP would be solved if only I could say e.g. (theoretical doesn't work!)

`javaOptions in Test += "-Devolutions.prefix=conf/testdatabase/"`

and then have:

```
conf/
    evolutions/default/1.sql 
                       2.sql
    testdatabase/evolutions/default/1.sql -> ../../../evolutions/default/1.sql
```

I will be happy with any other solution for this problem that I am not aware of ... as long as it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your test configuration file turn off the default application of evolutions by adding this line.

```
# Evolutions should not be applied by default
play.evolutions.db.default.enabled = false
```

Define a helper method in your test file which will apply Evolutions when called.

```
import play.api.db.Database
import play.api.db.evolutions.{DatabaseEvolutions, EvolutionsReader, ThisClassLoaderEvolutionsReader}

def applyEvolutions(database: Database,
                      evolutionsToSkip: Seq[Int],
                      evolutionsReader: EvolutionsReader = ThisClassLoaderEvolutionsReader,
                      autocommit: Boolean = true,
                      schema: String = ""): Unit = {
    val dbEvolutions = new DatabaseEvolutions(database, schema)
    val evolutions = dbEvolutions.scripts(evolutionsReader).filterNot(s => evolutionsToSkip.contains(s.evolution.revision))
    dbEvolutions.evolve(evolutions, autocommit)
  }
```

Then in your test override `beforeAll` and `afterAll` methods:

```
override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    applyEvolutions(database, Seq(2))
  }

  override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    Evolutions.cleanupEvolutions(database)
  }
```

You can access database as follows:

```
import play.api.db.{ DBApi, Database }
val databaseAPI = app.injector.instanceOf[DBApi]
val database = databaseAPI.database("default")
```